# Array to string conversion in elequent laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$assets = Asset::where('group_id', $request->group_id)->select('name')->get()->toArray();
dd($assets);
```

**output:**

```
    array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "name" => "wordpress"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "name" => "joomla"
      ]

]
```

**Error: Array to string conversion**

```
$assets = Asset::where('group_id', $request->group_id)->select('name')->get()->toArray();
dd(implode(',', $assets));
```

..............................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another way to do with collection `pluck()`,

```
$assets = Asset::where('group_id', $request->group_id)->get()->pluck('name')->implode(',');
```

Your output will be `Wordpress,joomla`